# RxJava - Observable which emits items which are new or changed

Tags: android, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I am a newbie in reactive world and trying to implement the following scenario with rxjava/rxandroid 2.x.

I have a local data set as ArrayList mItems in Application class. The same data set is synchronized with server and updated every time user opens the app. However before server returns the response, I want to display the local data set in RecycleView backed by adapter. **As soon as the response is returned, the adapter should update the list with delta and without disturbing the order in the UI.**

So far I have tried this:

```
public Observable<List<Item>> getItemsObservable() {
    Observable<List<Item>> observeApi = itemServiceAPI.getItemsForUser(accountId);
    if (mItems != null) {
        return Observable.just(mItems).mergeWith(observeApi);
    } else {
        return observeApi;
    }
}
```

To update the UI, the above method is invoked like this:

```
Observable<List<Item>> itemsObservable = appContext.getItemsObservable();
            itemsObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new DefaultObserver<List<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Item> Items) {
                            // Code to update the adapter
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

With this I get the onNext called twice for each local data set and remote data set. How to achieve the desired functionality? Does it need use of filter operators to exclude items?

What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'startWith' operator: it subscribes to different observable first. 
`appContext.getItemsObservable()
  .startWith(localCacheObservable)
  .subscribe(adapter::updateData)`

Adapter's update data should handle diff calculations.

Comment: Okay. I'll try this first.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

First of all, why are you using `Observable.just(mItems)` ??? That's unnecessary.

Your code should look like

```
itemServiceAPI.getItemsForUser(accountId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DefaultObserver<List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Item> Items) {
                    // Code to update the adapter

                    mAdapter.updateItems(items);

                    /* method in adapter class
                    * 
                    *  public void updateItems(List<Item> mList) {
                              this.items.addAll(mList);
                              notifyDataSetChanged();
                          }
                    * */
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Here, your adapter will be updated in `onNext`. make sure before calling API, you have to set your adapter with local items.

Comment: The `just` would make observer emit items which are available locally. In my question I have mentioned I need to display the data set to user even before the server responds. What i am trying to achieve is, using the same observer which observes on local as well as remote and get triggered with exclusive items.